# Does std::unordered_map use hashes internally?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

Given

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, sf::Texture> container;
```

will

```
container["myKey"] = myTexture;
```

transform "myKey" into a hash behind the scenes?

If so, are duplicate hashes possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

No, hashes don't have to be unique: if two keys hash to the same value, the keys themselves have to be compared to establish whether or not they are equal.